# Flutter type "null" is not a sub-type of type "string"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load some data from a json file called  `recipe.json` from my assets folder. The model that I've written is :

```
class RecipeModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String videoLink;
  final String author;
  final String category;
  final String time;
  RecipeModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.videoLink,
    required this.author,
    required this.category,
    required this.time,
  });

  factory RecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return RecipeModel(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      videoLink: json['videoLink'],
      author: json['author'],
      category: json['category'],
      time: json['time'],
    );
  }
}
```

And the function that fetches the data:

```
  Future _getRecipeData() async {
    // var response = await http.get(
    //   Uri.https("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", 'users'),
    // );
    String response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/json/recipe.json');
    var result = json.decode(response);
    List<RecipeModel> recipes = [];
    for (var i in result) {
      RecipeModel recipe = RecipeModel(
        id: i['id'],
        name: i['name'],
        videoLink: i['videoLink'],
        author: i['author'],
        category: i['category'],
        time: i['time'],
      );
      recipes.add(recipe);
    }
    print(recipes.length);
  }
```

And I'm loading the data when the page loads:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRecipeData();
  }
```

But I get an error which says: `Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`. Is there something that I'm missing?

**Edit 1:**
here's my `recipe.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "Kacchi Biriyani",
        "videoLink": "PQSagzssvUQ",
        "author": "Alan Ford",
        "category":"Biriyani",
        "time": "15 min",
        "steps": {
            "step 1": "lorel ipsum dolor",
            "step 2": "lorel ipsum dolor",
            "step 3": "lorel ipsum dolor",
            "step 4": "lorel ipsum dolor"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "name": "Mughal Biriyani",
        "videoLink": "PQSagzssvUQ",
        "author": "Ricky James",
        "category":"Biriyani",
        "time": "10 min",
        "steps": {
            "step 1": "lorel ipsum dolor",
            "step 2": "lorel ipsum dolor",
            "step 3": "lorel ipsum dolor",
            "step 4": "lorel ipsum dolor"
        }
    }
]
```

**Update 1:**

```
  List<RecipeModel> _recipes = [];
  Future _getRecipeData() async {
    // var response = await http.get(
    //   Uri.https("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", 'users'),
    // );
    String response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/json/recipe.json');
    var data = json.decode(response);

    
    for (var i in data) {
      RecipeModel recipe = RecipeModel(
        id: i['id'],
        name: i['name'],
        videoLink: i['videoLink'],
        author: i['author'],
        category: i['category'],
        time: i['time'],
      );
      _recipes.add(recipe);
    }
    print(_recipes);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRecipeData();
    print(_recipes);
  }
```

Comment: print your `result ` before the loop and check if its loaded well first

Comment: @MoaidALRazhy yeah the json file prints successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `fromJson` and `_getRecipeData` your are accessing id like `json['id']` and `i['id']`

however in your data it is **_id** there is underscore missing.

you can use null operator to avoid nulls also like this

```
 RecipeModel recipe = RecipeModel(
        id: i['id'] ?? "",
        name: i['name'] ?? "",
        videoLink: i['videoLink'] ?? "",
        author: i['author'] ?? "",
        category: i['category'] ?? "",
        time: i['time'] ?? "",
      );
```

Comment: hi, your solution worked but it seems my list is still empty. I printed out the the list that is supposed to hold my data but nothing is in it. I've updated my code with the newer one'